# Number of machine cycles in microprocessor 8085

Tags: microprocessor, 8085

The DCR instruction in MP 8085 has has 1 machine cycle, i.e. opcode fetch cycle. But the DCR M instruction has 3 machine cycles. What are those three machine cycles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The \$3\$ machine cycles are:

1. Opcode Fetch Cycle
2. Memory Read Cycle
3. Memory Write Cycle

Internally, depending on the opcode, each machine cycle takes from \$3\$ to \$6\$ T-cycles (or T-states) to accomplish the \$1\$ machine cycle.

T-states are one clock period long, and the instruction length is measured in T-states.

For example, a typical Opcode Fetch has \$4\$ T-states: the first \$3\$, T\$1\$-T\$3\$ are used to fetch the instruction, and T\$4\$ is used to decode it.

Instruction cycles take from \$1\$ to \$6\$ machine cycles.

The 8085 also has some external status pins that can be used to identify which machine cycle it is currently in.  These are the \$\mathrm{IO/\overline{M}}\$ signal, the \$\mathrm{S0}\$ and \$\mathrm{S1}\$ signals.

Opcode Fetch: \$\mathrm{IO/\overline{M}} = 0,\$ \$\mathrm{S0} = 1\$ and \$\mathrm{S1} = 1\$

Memory Read: \$\mathrm{IO/\overline{M}} = 0,\$ \$\mathrm{S0} = 0\$ and \$\mathrm{S1} = 1\$

Memory Write: \$\mathrm{IO/\overline{M}} = 0,\$ \$\mathrm{S0} = 1\$ and \$\mathrm{S1} = 0\$

There is also I/O read and write cycles, which are not part of this DCR M instruction, but when those cycles are active in other opcodes the control/status pin \$\mathrm{IO/\overline{M}} = 1\$

Comment: 8085 instructions can be 1, 2, or 3 bytes.  I haven't done 8085 assembly for a long time, but I suspect that the simple DCR instruction is a single byte - it will act on a register which can be encoded in one byte along with the instruction.  The DCR M instruction may act on a location in memory, so needs an additional two bytes for the memory address, making a total of three memory reads to get the full instruction.

Comment: it's been over 25 years since I did anything on the 8085 too ... DCR M is Decrement Memory instruction but it's only 1 byte opcode. It encodes (HL) in the opcode and decrements the contents of memory that (HL) refers to. So it's as I said, 3 machine cycles.